# Openpyxl datetime Error When Saving Workbook

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, openpyxl

I am trying to write to a *.xlsx file with the openpyxl module. I have downloaded it using pip install on Ubuntu 14.04.

I am loading in a *.xlsx file that is a Bill Of Materials template I use that was previously made in Excel and I can open it just fine in Libre Office and Kingsoft Office. My intention is to load it and fill in some cells with some strings.

My function looks like this:

```
def writeBOM(parts, projectname):
    '''
    Take the ordered and grouped part info and
    write it to a standard BOM and save it
    '''
    StandardBOMFILE = '/home/jesse/Digi-Parser/SampleFiles/StandardBOM.xlsx'

    wb = load_workbook(filename=StandardBOMFILE)
    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('BOM')

    r = 8
    # Fill BOM
    for i, part in enumerate(parts):
       sheet.cell(row = r+i,column = 1).value = part.designator
       sheet.cell(row = r+i,column = 2).value = part.evalue + ' ' + part.package
       sheet.cell(row = r+i, column = 3).value = part.qty
    projectBOMname = projectname + 'BOM' + '.xlsx'
    wb.save(projectBOMname)
```

The values that I am putting into the cells are just strings.

However when I run this I get the following Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    202             else:
    203                 filename = fname
--> 204             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/home/jesse/Digi-Parser/SheetOrganizer.py in <module>()
    232         prjpath = '/home/jesse/Digi-Parser/SampleFiles/'
    233         prjname = 'Water Use Monitor'
--> 234         things = csvToBOM(prjpath, prjname)

/home/jesse/Digi-Parser/SheetOrganizer.py in csvToBOM(projectpath, projectname)
    223         orderedBody = combineSameComponents(reorderParts(body))
    224 
--> 225         writeBOM(orderedBody, projectname)
    226 
    227 

/home/jesse/Digi-Parser/SheetOrganizer.py in writeBOM(parts, projectname)
    192        sheet.cell(row = r+i, column = 3).value = part.qty
    193     projectBOMname = projectname + 'BOM' + '.xlsx'
--> 194     wb.save(projectBOMname)
    195 
    196 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.pyc in save(self, filename)
    265             save_dump(self, filename)
    266         else:
--> 267             save_workbook(self, filename)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.pyc in save_workbook(workbook, filename)
    183     """
    184     writer = ExcelWriter(workbook)
--> 185     writer.save(filename)
    186     return True
    187 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.pyc in save(self, filename)
    166         """Write data into the archive."""
    167         archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED)
--> 168         self.write_data(archive)
    169         archive.close()
    170 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.pyc in write_data(self, archive)
     78         archive.writestr(ARC_WORKBOOK_RELS, write_workbook_rels(self.workbook))
     79         archive.writestr(ARC_APP, write_properties_app(self.workbook))
---> 80         archive.writestr(ARC_CORE, write_properties_core(self.workbook.properties))
     81         if self.workbook.loaded_theme:
     82             archive.writestr(ARC_THEME, self.workbook.loaded_theme)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/workbook.pyc in write_properties_core(properties)
     65     SubElement(root, '{%s}created' % DCTERMS_NS,
     66                {'{%s}type' % XSI_NS: '%s:W3CDTF' % DCTERMS_PREFIX}).text = \
---> 67                    datetime_to_W3CDTF(properties.created)
     68     SubElement(root, '{%s}modified' % DCTERMS_NS,
     69                {'{%s}type' % XSI_NS: '%s:W3CDTF' % DCTERMS_PREFIX}).text = \

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/date_time.pyc in datetime_to_W3CDTF(dt)
     54 def datetime_to_W3CDTF(dt):
     55     """Convert from a datetime to a timestamp string."""
---> 56     return datetime.datetime.strftime(dt, W3CDTF_FORMAT)
     57 
     58 

ValueError: year=1899 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900
```

I can not figure out how to fix this. I don't need to have Excel installed on my computer do I? It seems the issue is in the date_time.py file in the openpyxl package and that the variable 'dt' is set to 1899 for some reason.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed on the mailing list this looks like a bug in the Python datetime library.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

There is not a problem with Python 3.3 or 3.4